# Is converting a byte array representing a file to a String in java a security risk?

Tags: java, string, security, arrays

I'm protecting software from XML expansion attacks and I want to run a file stored as a byte array through an XMLReader to test for expansion loops. Is it safe to simply create a string from the byte array or is this opening my software to a whole new area of possible exploits?

```
String xml = new String ( myByteArray );
```

Comment: Given it is insecure to get a password as a `String` using Java (it is recommend to use `char[]` instead), I *suspect* the same would apply here..

Comment: If you want to store a byte array in a String you have to use a correct encoding such as BASE64 encoding for instance. Not all bytes correspond to characters, so you will lose data (in java String are UTF-16, it is different to C String)!

Comment: "Is it safe to simply create a string from the byte array" it is never a good idea to do that, because you are assuming the bytes are in the default character encoding. That assumption could be false. But a *security* risk: not in itself.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, currently I'm attempting to construct an xmlreader using the ByteArrayInputStream  as an argument to an InputSource, I'll update with how this works

Comment: `String(byte[])` uses whatever character encoding happens to be set as default, and so should not be used. In particularly, mapping of special characters from bytes may be different from expected. XML may specify character set within itself (incredibly bad idea, but that's the spec), so isn't suitable for storing in a `String`. / The idea of using arrays for passwords (private keys, SSNs, etc.) is that you have a chance of being able to erase the date from memory, which probably does not apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented.

As Raedwald pointed out it is not necessarily a security concern but data may be lost when converting byte[] to String.

I have found this method to work and it seems to be secure. With this code a SAXParseException will be thrown at 100,000 expansions. This limit can be reduced with security manager or setting the system property or at runtime using -DentityExpansionLimit=|number|

```
InputStream textReader = new ByteArrayInputStream ( myByteArray);
SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
try {
        XMLReader reader = parserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        reader.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( textReader );
        reader.parse(inputSource);
}
```